# mostrar Total Items en ngx-pagination Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

Necesito mostrar en mi paginado el total de items que tengo en mi lista pero no logro hacerlo, estoy usando la libreria ngx-pagination para angular pero solo me muestra pagina por pagina pero no me muestra la totalidad de registros que tengo.

```
<table class="table">
            <thead class="bg-danger text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th>Área</th>
                    <th>Estado Revisión</th>
                    <th>Paso Revisión</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Observaciones...</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let proveedor of ListHistorico | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: page, totalItems: ListHistorico.length }; let i = index" (click)='seleccionIndex(i)' [ngClass]="{'data-selected':indexId === (i)}" style="cursor:pointer" >
                    <td>{{proveedor.AUDAT}}</td>
                    <td>{{proveedor.VBELN}}</td>
                    <td>{{proveedor.VBELN}}</td>
                    <td>{{proveedor.VBELN}}</td>
                    <td>{{proveedor.VBELN}}</td>
                    <td>{{proveedor.VBELN}}</td>
                </tr>                                        
            </tbody>                                    
        </table>
        <div class="card d-flex flex-row pl-3 pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 card col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 col-sm-12 align-items-center h-100 y justify-content-center" >
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageCuantia = $event" directionLinks="true" previousLabel="Anterior" nextLabel="Siguiente" ></pagination-controls>
        </div>
```

este es mi codigo en donde recorro una lista, obtengo el total de items pero no se como mostrarlo en mi paginado.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar la propiedad `getTotalItems()`, aquí te dejo la documentación: https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/README.md